# Dropbox Integration with iOS

Tags: ios, dropbox

Does Dropbox API for iOS provides the functionality for renaming the folder / files in the Dropbox. Also does it supports functionality for deleting the folder / files from iOS?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FYI, as of May 2012, Apple has began to reject apps that use the Dropbox API.

Comment: Is there any other way to confirm this. Also any other option to solve this issue.

Comment: Dropbox has a new SDK that satisfies Apple's App Store requirements.  [Link to SDK](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=59350&page=4&replies=125#post-431784)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  Look at the Dropbox documentation for iOS [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/reference/sdk).

Quick example:

```
DBRestClient *dbClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];
[dbClient moveFrom:fromPath toPath:toPath];  // Rename
[dbClient deletePath:path];                  // Delete
```

Comment: Thank you bbarnhat. Many people are saying that Apple rejects app which integrated. Do you know any way to solve this.

Comment: What are the callbacks for deleting/renaming?

Comment: - (void)stepComplete {[restClient performSelector:@selector(loadMetadata:) withObject:@"/" afterDelay:.05];
}- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client deletedPath:(NSString *)path{[self stepComplete];}
how to call this funtion

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{NSArray *paths=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cprog.pdf"];
 DBRestClient *dbClient = [[DBRestClient alloc] initWithSession:[DBSession sharedSession]];[dbClient deletePath:filePath];
but crack may app

Answer (score 2):

You can't rename a file or folder(up to v1.2.2). to do this you can follow below steps.

rename a file,
create a new file with new name and delete old file.

rename a folder,
create a new folder,
move the contents into this folder from your old folder,
and delete the old folder. (make sure all the files are moved before delete).

thanx.

Comment: This steps can be tedious if the file size is larger. We first need to download into local documents directory and then create it with new name. AND the case of folder is very hectic. We need to download all files in the folder to documents directory and then upload them back.. Need some other way for achieving this.

Comment: you don't need to download the content you can move the files form location to location.
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#fileops-move